# Masking Policy Architecture: can the masking policy be set across multiple databases or schemas?

Tags: sql, security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, masking

I am exploring using "masking policies" for my current company. Currently, they leverage secure views for PII information. Ideally, I am trying to use masking policies to hide this information. I am seeing in the documentation that masking policy is a schema level object.

We have hundreds if not thousands of schemas and am wondering if its possible to use a masking policy across many of the schemas? Or even better a masking policy at the account level across multiple databases and schemas?

According to this [blog](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/column-level-security-in-snowflake/), it seems possible.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people. Following snowflakes documentation I created a role called "masking_admin" that is able to apply the masking policy across multiple databases and schemas. Technically the policy resides in the schema but can be applied more broadly. Cheers and best of luck!